# "Выдвинул на выборах" или "Выдвинул на выборы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Как правильно: "Он выдвинул свою кандидатуру на выборах" или "Он выдвинул свою кандидатуру на выборы"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строго говоря, следовало бы построить предложение так: "Он выдвинул свою кандидатуру **на должность** президента", но встречается и такое: "Он выдвинул свою кандидатуру **на выборы** президента". А "**на выборах**" (т.е. в ходе выборов) кандидатуру выдвигать уже поздновато.